# Aging algorithm for insurance policy

Tags: algorithm

This may sound very simple, but these parts of my brain are a bit rusty from disuse.  I need to report on insurance policies, stating whether a policy is current, in advance/credit, or behind/in arrears.  Am I correct in presuming it is as simple as below, providing the monthly payments remain constant?

```
Received = Tally of all monthly payments on the policy.
Expected = Policy age in months x monthly premium.
If Received < Expected, policy is in arrears.
If Received > Expected, policy is paid in advance.
If Received == Expected, policy is current.
```

Comment: Monthly payments do not necessarily stay constant on policies.

Comment: Is there a question in here somewhere?

Comment: Yes, @Jim, "It is this simple right?" followed by the "this" in the question, but I have tried to make that clearer with my edit.

Comment: @David, I have not been asked to cater for changing monthly payments.  If I am, I will use and audit table and tally instead of mere multiplication.

Comment: The headless closing monster attacks again! I'm starting to believe that if a question is not about a syntax or algorithm issue, many people think it's off topic here. What is programming then? The outside world is full of problems ... don't look _only_ at your code.

Comment: This is a vague question. Do you even consider the payment and billing cycle dates?

Comment: It is not vague but purposefully general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no changes to the premium, and no interest charged on late payments, then yes you are correct.  That doesn't typically align with reality though.

There could however be nuances (fencepost errors) arising from when a premium is supposed to be paid (e.g. you pay at the end of the month for the previous month's coverage).

Comment: Thanks @Mark.  To complicate things even more, there are actually two premiums: that paid to the broker by the policyholder, and that paid to the agency by the broker.  The scant spec I have is luckily just for the broker-policyholder relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Just one small potential complication:
"Current" and "in arrears" may be an overlapping set - certainly it is possible, on life policies for a policy to have some (a small number of) premiums not paid, but the policy still be considered current, with a debt against the potential payout.